# How do I attach sources to a prebuilt static C library in Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, debugging, android-ndk

I have a pre-built static library (.a) and the source code for it. How do I attach the source so so I can step through it while debugging in Eclipse with gdb?

Comment: This may help: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html  Note you can set source directories in your .gdbinit file too, which may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment, but I can add some more detail WRT @massimo's answer. Quickly, it can't be helped unless you've got a library compiled with "-g". But there's more than that...

In the world of GCC, building with "-g" does a number of things. On top of all the symbols it keeps, it also keeps the original location of the source directory and code file in the ".debug_info" section:

```
objdump -g liblib_g.a 

lib_g.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of the .debug_info section:

  Compilation Unit @ offset 0x0:
   Length:        0x8d (32-bit)
   Version:       4
   Abbrev Offset: 0x0
   Pointer Size:  8
 <0><b>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
     <c>   DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0x0): GNU C 4.8.1 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -fstack-protector    
    <10>   DW_AT_language    : 1    (ANSI C)
    <11>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0xec): lib.c   
    <15>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : (indirect string, offset: 0x86): /home/me/path/to/my/archive 
    <19>   DW_AT_low_pc      : 0x0  
    <21>   DW_AT_high_pc     : 0x15 
    <29>   DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0x0  
    ...it goes on and on...
```

When this is done, GDB will just *know* where the source code is, and stepping through the code will of course work.

Now, what about if it was built with "-g", but somewhere else (like... some other computer...)? Well, when you try to step through that code, Eclipse will prompt you to go find it:

[image]

or you can set it up yourself:

- Open up "Debug Configurations" and edit your current debug configuration:

[image: click here to start]

- When you open up that menu, select your configuration (probably the project's name), and then the "Source" tab:

[image: add source tab]

- Click the "Add" button, and select "Path Mapping" (then, of course, hit "OK"):

[image: select add path mapping]

- Map the original path (under "Compilation path") to the path that you've stored the code in (click the dots in "Local file system path" -- this will bring up a file system explorer):

[image: map that thang]

At this point, Eclipse should know enough to step through everything! Again... this is if and only if the library was built with debugging symbols (yes, "-g")...

Answer (score 6):

You can't step through the source code if your library has not been compiled with the debug option (gcc -g, assuming you are using gcc). The easiest thing would be to compile the library yourself in Eclipse, in debug mode, then link your program against the newly-compiled library.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to compile the library source in with your project, which would allow you to step into the library as though it where your code (since it is at this point). I am not aware of another method for debugging library code.